# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setLocalizer' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

```
import Calendar from 'react-big-calendar'
Calendar.setLocalizer(Calendar.momentLocalizer(moment))
```

With plugins version:

```
"moment": "^2.24.0"
"react-big-calendar": "^0.23.0"
```

After updating react big calendar package i'm getting this error. I have installed the package multiple times after update .

But getting this error `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setLocalizer' of undefined "`.

I have already read answers related to `"Cannot read property 'momentLocalizer' of undefined "` , but its not working for me. please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer } from 'react-big-calendar';
import moment from 'moment';

const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);
```

In your JSX:

```
  <div style={{ height: '500pt'}}>
              <Calendar
                 ....
                defaultDate={moment().toDate()}
                localizer={localizer}
              />
            </div>
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

This would work:

```
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer } from 'react-big-calendar'
import moment from 'moment'

const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment)

const MyCalendar = props => (
  <div>
    <Calendar
      localizer={localizer}
      events={myEventsList}
      startAccessor="start"
      endAccessor="end"
      style={{ height: 500 }}
    />
  </div>
)
```